# Java String iterations

Tags: java, python, strings, iteration

I am working with some Java code. Basically I have a wrapper class that holds a string and implements some of the many useful python string methods in Java. My goal here is to implement the Python method `.ljust` and my hope is to be as efficient as possible. Currently, I am using a while loop which I imagine is terrible inefficient especially because it includes a `+=`. What's more, I am not sure which of the following alternatives is more efficient

```
String news = "";
news = this.toString();
int length = news.length();
while (length < size) {
        news += " ";
        length++;
}
return new PythonString(news);
```

In the above case, `news.length()` is only called once, but now there is an extra `int` and a new instruction `length++`.

The other option would be

```
String news = "";
news = this.toString();
while (news.length() < size) {
        news += " ";
}
return new PythonString(news);
```

In this case, `news.length()` is called every time.

I am interested in perspectives on which of these alternatives is most efficient as well as any other optimizations you could provide for this method, which is meant to pad a string with `size` spaces to the right so that all following characters line up at the same column.

Comment: you should actually *measure* the differences. There are several options to do this, as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am interested in perspectives on which of these alternatives is most efficient

Using `StringBuilder` in the loop instead of `+=` will likely be far *faster* than either of your current approaches, especially as `size - length` gets big. I'm not sure how much more space it would take.

Comment: Space-wise, likely normally less as you won't need to constantly reallocate.

Answer (score 5):

The String class can do this already, see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/4217399. You can always look at the source of the String class to check how it's done, should be fairly optimized there, as it's a part of the JDK. It's actually offloaded to the java.util.Formatter class.

Comment: I thought I looked through the documentation, that is why i implemented these, but thanks for the info

Answer (score 4):

What your code seems to be doing is to add spaces at the end of a string to make it at least `size` long.

You could write it in a way that better expresses your intent:

```
String news = this.toString(); //no need to allocate an empty string first
int padding = size - news.length();

return new PythonString(appendSpaces(news, padding));
```

And have a utility method that does the appending:

```
private static String appendSpaces(String s, int n) {
  if (n <= 0) return s;

  char[] spaces = new char[n];
  Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');
  return s.concat(new String(spaces));
}
```

This will also be more efficient than your approach of concatenating the spaces one by one.

Comment: This. No need to reinvent the wheel when all the cogs are already there!